# jest Unexpected token (15:29) on "<"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I got jest working on my react app and I'm trying to run tests, but I'm getting an error. When I run the test with `"scripts": {"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"}` almost every test works. I had to change my tester to `"test":"jest"` to get the last test working, but now the test are crashing on compile because the < in the multiple `shallow(<ReactPage />)` is throwing an error.

From my understanding of the code, my test should be fine. Should be some setting for jest that I have to make in the project.json file to fix this error?

Test

```
import {shallow, mount, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import jest from 'jest';
import ReactPage from './App';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it('renders ReactPage without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render( <ReactPage /> , div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "client-charts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "recharts": "^1.1.0",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-snapshot": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && react-snapshot",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a step to process the JSX. If you are using babel, add a `react` preset to your `.babelrc` file. More info can be found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#additional-configuration

Comment: The test now compiles, but jest says the test fails on "<" on all my test where "<ReactPage />" is used